# FlatFileItemReader skips first record?

Tags: spring-batch

I am writing my first project using Spring Batch 5.1.6. My steps read a flat file for parameters and then execute an SQL query using those parameters.

The problem I am getting is that the first record is skipped every time.

I am wondering whether this is a configuration problem.

```
@Configuration
public class Query1Config {
  class QueryItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Query1, Query1> {
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
      this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public Query1 process(Query1 query) throws Exception {
      List<Query1> list;
      String sql;

      // Retrieve single row result set.
      sql = "SELECT id, name, zip FROM JEREMY.CUSTOMERS WHERE id = ?";
      list = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new Object[] {query.getId()}, 
        new int[] {Types.INTEGER}, 
        new BeanPropertyRowMapper(Query1.class));
      return list.get(0);
    }
  }

  class QueryFieldSetMapper implements FieldSetMapper<Query1> {
    @Override
    public Query1 mapFieldSet(FieldSet fieldSet) throws BindException {
      Query1 query = new Query1();
      query.setId(fieldSet.readInt(0));
      return query;
    }
  }  

  @Bean("query1ItemReader")
  protected ItemReader<Query1> queryItemReader() throws Exception {
    final FileSystemResource resource = new FileSystemResource("input_query1.csv");
    FlatFileItemReader<Query1> itemReader;
    DefaultLineMapper<Query1> lineMapper;

    itemReader = new FlatFileItemReader<Query1>();
    lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<Query1>();
    itemReader.setResource(resource);
    lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer());
    lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(new Query1Config() .new QueryFieldSetMapper());
    itemReader.setLineMapper(lineMapper);
    itemReader.open(new ExecutionContext());
    itemReader.read();
    return itemReader;
  }

  @Bean("query1ItemProcessor")
  protected ItemProcessor<Query1, Query1> queryItemProcessor() throws Exception {
    return new Query1Config() .new QueryItemProcessor();
  }

  @Bean("query1ItemWriter")
  public FlatFileItemWriter queryItemWriter() {
    final FileSystemResource resource = new FileSystemResource("output_query1.txt");
    FlatFileItemWriter<Query1> fileWriter;
    LineAggregator<Query1> lineAggregator;

    fileWriter = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();
    fileWriter.setResource(resource);
    lineAggregator = createQueryLineAggregator();
    fileWriter.setLineAggregator(lineAggregator);
    return fileWriter;
  }

  private LineAggregator<Query1> createQueryLineAggregator() {
    DelimitedLineAggregator<Query1> lineAggregator;
    FieldExtractor<Query1> fieldExtractor;

    lineAggregator = new DelimitedLineAggregator<>();
    fieldExtractor = createQueryFieldExtractor();
    lineAggregator.setFieldExtractor(fieldExtractor);
    return lineAggregator;
  }

  private FieldExtractor<Query1> createQueryFieldExtractor() {
    BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<Query1> extractor;

    extractor = new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<Query1>();
    extractor.setNames(new String[] {"id", "name", "zip"});
    return extractor;
  }
}
```

Everything works as expected, except that the first record is skipped.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `itemReader.read()` in the `queryItemReader` method. This is the cause of your issue.

Spring Batch will call lifecycle methods (`open`, `update`, `close`) on the item reader/writer so you don't have to call them yourself. In your case, the bean definition of the item reader should be something like:

```
@Bean("query1ItemReader")
protected ItemReader<Query1> queryItemReader() throws Exception {
   final FileSystemResource resource = new FileSystemResource("input_query1.csv");
   FlatFileItemReader<Query1> itemReader;
   DefaultLineMapper<Query1> lineMapper;

   itemReader = new FlatFileItemReader<Query1>();
   lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<Query1>();
   itemReader.setResource(resource);
   lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer());
   lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(new Query1Config() .new QueryFieldSetMapper());
   itemReader.setLineMapper(lineMapper);
   return itemReader;
}
```